# Is $\hom_{R}(M,T)$ locally compact whenever $M$ is, $R$ being a compact DVR?

Tags: abstract-algebra, harmonic-analysis

An important result in Harmonic analysis states that the Pontryagin dual $\widehat{A}$ of an locally compact abelian group $A$, defined as $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,T)$ where the hom is taken over continuous group homomorphisms and $T=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, is again locally compact.

Here and always I will always say "(locally) compact" when I mean "(locally) compact Hausdoff".

Recently I have been thinking a lot about how this sort of sitatuion generalizes when we examine morphisms of modules over rings other than $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, I have been curious about the following:

> If $R$ is a compact Discrete Valuation Ring does that imply that the dual $\widehat{M}$ of a locally compact module $M$ will be locally compact, where I define $\widehat{M}=\hom_R(M,T)$ with hom taken over continuous module homomorphisms and $T=\mathrm{Frac}(R)/R=K/R$?

The standard proofs for abelian groups use the theory of integration heavily and I'm not figuring out how to generalize that theory to the case of modules over other rings.

Comment: Just to check that I'm not missing anything, compactness for a DVR is equivalent to completeness and the residue field being finite, right?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, that is exactly correct

Comment: Is it true that a locally compact module module over a compact DVR must actually have a neighborhood base of compact sets that are *submodules*?  This seems plausible, and I can prove the dual is always locally compact if it is true.

Comment: @EricWofsey that’s an interesting question. I found a link to a computer algebra system which seems to claim that topological modules over non-archemedian rings (by which I assume they mean local complete) have a basis of open sub modules near the identity: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/topology/algebra/nonarchimedean/bases.html. Taking the closures of these sub modules will again yield sub modules, which will eventually be compact.

Comment: Also, I found the following paper which discusses the subject: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF02018165. I am trying to decipher it, and I should be able to say whether it gives you the result you want soon.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing the notation there but I don't think your interpretation can be correct.  For instance, there exist nontrivial topological vector spaces over finite fields which are connected.

Comment: @EricWofsey The paper I linked does not prove that there is a base for the topology consisting of open submodules. They call topological modules with this property "linear", but do not prove that any nice families of modules necessarily have linear topologies.

Comment: @EricWofsey Could you answer the question with your partial solution assuming that the module has a basis of compact submodules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to the problem, based of Eric Wofsey's partial response. Given any $f\in \widehat{M}$, $\ker(f)$ is clopen and so by local compactness there is an inclusion of subsets $U\leq K \leq \ker(f)$ with $U$ open and $K$ compact. Letting $V(A,B)$ denote the set consisting of maps in $\widehat{M}$ mapping $A$ into $B$, we obtain an inclusion of subsets

$$V(\ker(f),0)\leq V(K,0)\leq V(U,0).$$

Since $f\in V(\ker(f),0)$, we have that $V(K,0)$ is an open neighborhood of $f$. It remains to show that $V(U,0)$ is compact. To do this, we note that a morphism acts by $0$ on $U$ if and only if it acts by $0$ on the (open) submodule $\tilde{U}$ generated by $U$. Hence, $V(U,0)=V(\tilde{U},0)=\widehat{M/\tilde{U}}$ so by the second paragraph of Eric Wofsey's answer we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer.  Suppose that $M$ is not just locally compact, but has a neighborhood base of $0$ consisting of compact *submodules*.  Then I claim $\widehat{M}$ is locally compact.  To prove this, let $f\in\widehat{M}$.  Since $T$ is discrete, $\ker(f)$ is open, so it contains some compact open submodule $K\subseteq M$.  The set $U$ of continuous homomorphisms $M\to T$ that vanish on $K$ is then open in the compact-open topology.  I claim $U$ is compact, so it is a compact neighborhood of $f$ in $\widehat{M}$.

To prove this, note first that $U$ can naturally be identified with $\widehat{M/K}$.  Since $K$ is open, $M/K$ is discrete, so the compact-open topology on $\widehat{M/K}$ is just the product topology.  Also, $M/K$ must be a torsion $R$-module (if $x\in M/K$ were a non-torsion element then continuity of scalar multiplication would imply $Rx$ is not discrete).  So $\widehat{M/K}$ is actually a subspace of the product $\prod_{x\in M/K}\pi^{-n_x}R/R$, where $\pi$ is a uniformizer and $n_x$ is such that $\pi^{n_x}x=0$.  Since $R$ is compact, so is $\pi^{-n_x}R/R\cong R/(\pi^{n_x})$, and thus so is the product $\prod_{x\in M/K}\pi^{-n_x}R/R$.  The subset of this product consisting of the homomorphisms $M/K\to T$ is closed, and thus $\widehat{M/K}$ is compact.

Comment: It seems like you are asserting the existence of a submodule $K$ that is simultaneously compact and open; I cannot see how that is justified from your givens. To me, what follows from the definitions is an inclusion of submodules $U\leq K\leq \ker(f)$ with $U$ open and $K$ compact. At this point, the definition of the compact open topology gives us that $\widehat{M/K}$ is open and your argument in the second paragraph gives us that $\widehat{M/U}$ is compact, yielding the desired conclusion of local compactness.

Comment: A submodule that contains a neighborhood of $0$ is automatically open, since it then contains a neighborhood of each of its points.

Comment: Of course! I totally forgot about that fact. Using this I can deduce a full answer; I posted it below.